# java.io.EOFException(read object)

Tags: java

I have 3 objects written in the file. The program outputs these 3 objects and then this java.io.EOFException error.

writing to file:

```
try (ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file))) {
            planes.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(plane -> plane.productionYear));
            planes.forEach(plane -> {
                try {
                    objectOutputStream.writeObject(plane);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
            objectOutputStream.flush();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

reading the file:

```
try (ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file))) {
            Object o;
            while ((o = objectInputStream.readObject()) != null ){
                if (o.getClass().getName().contains("Plane")) {
                    Plane plane = (Plane) o;
                    plane.productionYear = plane.productionYearCopy;
                    plane.speed = plane.speedCopy;
                    plane.engine = plane.engineCopy;
 
                    System.out.println(plane);
 
                } else {
                    Ship ship = (Ship) o;
                    ship.productionYear = ship.productionYearCopy;
                    ship.speed = ship.speedCopy;
                    ship.engine = ship.engineCopy;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: java.io.EOFException is thrown by `objectInputStream.readObject()`, just catch the exception and assume that means there are no more objects to read

Comment: **or** start by writing the number of `Object`s to the stream. And then only reading that many `Object`s on the client. Instead of your current uncounted loop on the client.

Comment: Object Serialization/Streaming is brittle. It is very easy to create/save streams of Objects, only to find that they are incompatible with changes you make later to the class. XML and JSON are better ways of serializing objects